# API returns the same content in paginated response

Tags: bug, api, linked-questions, pagination

I'm trying to get [linked questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/1056728/linked?site=stackoverflow&page=4&pagesize=100) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/6908282) which currently has around [490 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1056728?lq=1). Since it has so many linked questions, I'm using a page size of 100 which is the maximum page size allowed, in order to reduce the number of API calls.

But I'm noticing that the response for the paginated calls is the same, i.e., I get the same response for [`page=1`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/1056728/linked?site=stackoverflow&page=1&pagesize=100) & [`page=4`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/1056728/linked?site=stackoverflow&page=4&pagesize=100). Below is a screenshot showing the same.

[image: Screenshot showing that paginated responses for linked questions is the same for Stack Exchange API]